# CLRegion hidden buffer?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, clregion

After coming across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16195041/1292230), I am concerned that there will not be an answer to the question, but I will hope, anyways.

I have setup a few geofences (most small and one large). I am using the simulator and I have outputted the radius of the large `CLRegion` and it tells me that the radius is 10881.98m around a certain coordinate, but when I simulate the geolocation to 11281.86m away from that same certain coordinate, it does not trigger the `locationManager:didExitRegion:` delegate method for the large region.

While the large region will not trigger `locationManager:didExitRegion:`, I have confirmed that the smaller regions will trigger the delegate method every time. Is there a reason why this is not firing? Is there a distance buffer around a region? Is it documented somewhere?

Any help would be great.

EDIT: From testing, I need to cut down the radius by around 45.28% in order to have the geofence trigger. Obviously this is not a great solution, as it is very imprecise and it goes against the whole idea of geofencing.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is an issue unique to the simulator. While CLRegion does not technically have a buffer or padding, the OS takes substantially longer to determine you have physically left the geofence area. On fences of that size, I would image it could take longer. On smaller regions, 100-200M, I've seen it take several minutes of driving, but easily 300-400M before triggering an event. From what the Apple Engineer told me at WWDC 2013, the OS takes its time in determining that you left. It is also harder for the system to determine you left because of its reliance on cell tower triangulation and known wifi networks. It needs to go well beyond the known networks before it can safely trigger the exit event.

I know it isn't an exact answer, but hopefully you'll understand a bit more how they work under the hood and what Apple's expectation of them is. Good luck.